# How to send Laravel error responses as JSON

Tags: php, laravel, http-error

Im just move to laravel 5 and im receiving errors from laravel in HTML page. Something like this:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1
NotFoundHttpException in Application.php line 756:
Persona no existe
in Application.php line 756
at Application->abort('404', 'Person doesnt exists', array()) in helpers.php line
```

When i work with laravel 4 all works fine, the errors are in json format, that way i could parse the error message and show a message to the user. An example of json error:

```
{"error":{
"type":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
"message":"Person doesnt exist",
"file":"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\backend1\\bootstrap\\compiled.php",
"line":768}}
```

How can i achieve that in laravel 5.

Sorry for my bad english, thanks a lot.

Comment: Specific to the abort function, it is possible to provide `abort` (and related `abort_if`, `abort_unless`) with a custom `Response` object (in the place where you'd put the status code) if you need more control than the options provided by the `abort` function. For example, if you need a JSON response (and cannot set the accept header to `application/json`), you could do `abort(new JsonResponse('A JSON string, could also be an array etc.', 403, ['Optional' => 'Headers'])`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I came here earlier searching for how to throw json exceptions anywhere in Laravel and the answer set me on the correct path. For anyone that finds this searching for a similar solution, here's how I implemented app-wide:

Add this code to the `render` method of `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
    return new JsonResponse($e->getMessage(), 422);
}
```

Add this to the method to handle objects:

```
if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {

    $message = $e->getMessage();
    if (is_object($message)) { $message = $message->toArray(); }

    return new JsonResponse($message, 422);
}
```

And then use this generic bit of code anywhere you want:

```
throw new \Exception("Custom error message", 422);
```

And it will convert all errors thrown after an ajax request to Json exceptions ready to be used any which way you want :-)

Comment: if Laravel 5.1, the return should read "return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 422);"

Comment: This works. When the handling code is not there, Laravel returns an HTTP 500 error, regardless of the specific error thrown in the code. E.g. `abort(403)` would return a 500 error for ajax requests. Did you experience the same? This must be a bug?

Comment: This saved my life. It's 2017 and I'm still using 5.1 so this is really useful for me. I passed 200 to the second argument when handling a FatalErrorException because I want the user to get an alert with a useful message rather than an obscure message like Internal Server Error. This lets the page render normally and gives the user useful feedback.

Answer (score 12):

**Laravel 5.1**

To keep my HTTP status code on unexpected exceptions, like 404, 500 403...

This is what I use (**app/Exceptions/Handler.php**):

```
 public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    $error = $this->convertExceptionToResponse($e);
    $response = [];
    if($error->getStatusCode() == 500) {
        $response['error'] = $e->getMessage();
        if(Config::get('app.debug')) {
            $response['trace'] = $e->getTraceAsString();
            $response['code'] = $e->getCode();
        }
    }
    return response()->json($response, $error->getStatusCode());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Laravel 5 offers an Exception Handler in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`. The `render` method can be used to render specific exceptions differently, i.e.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof API\APIError)
        return \Response::json(['code' => '...', 'msg' => '...']);
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Personally, I use `App\Exceptions\API\APIError` as a general exception to throw when I want to return an API error. Instead, you could just check if the request is AJAX (`if ($request->ajax())`) but I think explicitly setting an API exception seems cleaner because you can extend the `APIError` class and add whatever functions you need.

Answer (score 6):

Edit: Laravel 5.6 handles it very well without any change need, just be sure you are sending `Accept` header as `application/json`.

---

If you want to keep status code (it will be useful for front-end side to understand error type) I suggest to use this in your app/Exceptions/Handler.php:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {

        // this part is from render function in Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php
        // works well for json
        $exception = $this->prepareException($exception);

        if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Http\Exception\HttpResponseException) {
            return $exception->getResponse();
        } elseif ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException) {
            return $this->unauthenticated($request, $exception);
        } elseif ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException) {
            return $this->convertValidationExceptionToResponse($exception, $request);
        }

        // we prepare custom response for other situation such as modelnotfound
        $response = [];
        $response['error'] = $exception->getMessage();

        if(config('app.debug')) {
            $response['trace'] = $exception->getTrace();
            $response['code'] = $exception->getCode();
        }

        // we look for assigned status code if there isn't we assign 500
        $statusCode = method_exists($exception, 'getStatusCode') 
                        ? $exception->getStatusCode()
                        : 500;

        return response()->json($response, $statusCode);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: This worked really well, returns a huge json with stack trace, but can easly see last error at the top

Answer (score 4):

On Laravel 5.5, you can use `prepareJsonResponse` method in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` that will force response as JSON.

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    return $this->prepareJsonResponse($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: Nice and simple! But, Is it secure to show all that message to the client side?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {...}`

use

`if ($request->expectsJson()) {...}`

vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Concerns\InteractsWithContentTypes.php:42

```
public function expectsJson()
{
    return ($this->ajax() && ! $this->pjax()) || $this->wantsJson();
}
```

Comment: explain your answer so that OP and future readers will understand better.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` to catch HTTP Exceptions that were not validation errors:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    // converts errors to JSON when required and when not a validation error
    if ($request->expectsJson() && method_exists($exception, 'getStatusCode')) {
        $message = $exception->getMessage();
        if (is_object($message)) {
            $message = $message->toArray();
        }

        return response()->json([
            'errors' => array_wrap($message)
        ], $exception->getStatusCode());
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

By checking for the method `getStatusCode()`, you can tell if the exception can successfully be coerced to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Exception errors in json format then 
open the Handler class at **App\Exceptions\Handler** and customize it.
Here's an example for **Unauthorized** requests and **Not found** responses

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $exception->getMessage()], 403);
    }

    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $exception->getMessage()], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```